# How can I add to array my custom class and pass Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I simply want to add array to my custom class like "Dog" class to array and put it to Intent after that I want to get that extras using getIntent().getExtra() ... But I struggle with it.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


JSONArray jobList = (JSONArray) response.get("sonuclar");
JSONObject jsonObject;

for( int i = 0; i < jobList.length(); i++) {
     jsonObject = jobList.getJSONObject(i);

     String jobTitle     = jsonObject.getString("baslik");
     String firmName     = jsonObject.getString("firma_adi");
     String jobDate      = jsonObject.getString("tarih");
     String jobSummary   = "" ;
     String jobImageURL  = jsonObject.getString("logo");

      jobItem = new JobItem(jobTitle,firmName, jobDate, jobSummary, jobImageURL);
      list.add(jobItem);
}
 // this code will start new intent
 goJobListView(list);

/*  intent view  */
private void goJobListView(Object[] results) {

    Intent jobIntent = new Intent(this, JobListActivity.class);
    jobIntent.putExtra("job_data", results);
    startActivity(jobIntent);
}
```

Here is my trouble how can I get that custom class JobItem from another activity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add to array my custom class and pass Intent

Easy approach is mark custom class `Serializable` then use `intent.putExtra(key,custom_class_object_arraylist);` to send data to next Activity.

In next Activity use `intent.getSerializableExtra` method to get custom object Array from Intent:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<JobItem> job_data = 
    (ArrayList<JobItem>)intent.getSerializableExtra("job_data");
```

Second and good approach is mark `JobItem` class as `Parcelable` then use `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra` and `Intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra` to send and get list of custom objects from Intent.

For more help you can see following example:
[Android: Passing ArrayList of Object Within an Intent](http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/android-passing-arraylist-of-object-within-an-intent/)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this but apparently it will works!

Comment: Don't forget the parcelable option if you need speed!